# How do I insert a registered trademark, i.e., circle R, in MathJax?

Tags: support

I wanted to put a registered trademark in an answer I was providing in the Math StackExchange but could not find it in the MathJax reference page.

Comment: Was this part of a mathematical formula? If not you should not use MathJax but rather the Unicode symbol or the HTML entity. You can just copy it from here if you need it ® or type `&reg;` (The former even would also work in a formula.)

Comment: Thanks, now I have two solutions.

Answer (score 6):

While the other answer correctly answers the question how to get the symbol in MathJax I would like to stress that usually, and in the case that motivated the question, one should *not* use the MathJax command. The standard way to format things on this site is first, Markdown, and then a subset of HTML. MathJax is for *math*, and only this (for the most part).

Thus to write SomeRegisteredTrademark<sup>®</sup>  one would write `SomeRegisteredTrademark<sup>&reg;</sup>`and not `SomeRegisteredTrademark$^\circledR$`

One could also use the Unicode symbol directly instead of the HTML entity `&reg;`

Answer (score 2):

Use `\circledR` (which produces $\circledR$). Also, checkout [this website](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) for any questions about specific symbols. You just draw the symbol, and it tells you what the command is! Note that the site is for LaTex in general, so some of them won't work with MathJax, but many, many of them will.

Comment: Thanks for the link; it's a valuable resource. Too bad is not a PDF!

Comment: @CyeWaldman if you want a list with all or at least very very many LaTeX symbols there is one: http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: @quid I like to recommend [this list](http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys4610/phys4610_sp15/PHYS4610_sp15/Home_files/LaTeXSymbols.pdf) which is much less exhaustive but, IMHO, much more usable.

Comment: @Surb at that point we might as well recommend "our own" https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  Incidentally, your list does not contain the requested symbol. You do have a point though. In a way my answer was a bit tongue-in-cheek.